# How do I record if a value has been previously seen in R in a new column?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I hope this makes sense. I'm starting with a data frame (df) in R that looks like this:

| Sample Type | date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2020-10-05 |
| B | 2020-10-05 |
| A | 2020-10-06 |
| B | 2020-10-06 |
| B | 2020-10-06 |
| B | 2020-10-06 |
| A | 2020-10-10 |
| A | 2020-10-11 |
| A | 2020-10-11 |
| A | 2020-10-15 |
| A | 2020-10-16 |
| A | 2020-10-17 |

I want to create a 'rolling data frame' that tells me if the sample type "A" or "B" was sampled in the last 7 days with the first column as "sample type", second column as "date", third column as "Sampled in last 7 days". The final column would be populated with a "yes" or a "no".

I can get to a point where I have counts for each sample type per day using:

```
library(dplyr)

count_sampletype_day <- df %>%
  group_by(sample, date) %>%
  tally
```

But I may be going down the wrong route!

My expected output is:

| Sample Type | date | Sampled in last 7 days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020-10-05 | yes |
| B | 2020-10-05 | yes |
| A | 2020-10-06 | yes |
| B | 2020-10-06 | yes |
| A | 2020-10-07 | yes |
| B | 2020-10-07 | yes |
| A | 2020-10-08 | yes |
| B | 2020-10-08 | yes |
| A | 2020-10-09 | yes |
| B | 2020-10-09 | yes |
| A | 2020-10-10 | yes |
| B | 2020-10-10 | yes |
| A | 2020-10-11 | yes |
| B | 2020-10-11 | yes |
| A | 2020-10-12 | yes |
| B | 2020-10-12 | yes |
| A | 2020-10-13 | yes |
| B | 2020-10-13 | no |
| A | 2020-10-14 | yes |
| B | 2020-10-14 | no |
| A | 2020-10-15 | yes |
| B | 2020-10-15 | no |
| A | 2020-10-16 | yes |
| B | 2020-10-16 | no |
| A | 2020-10-17 | yes |
| B | 2020-10-17 | no |

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Thank you, I have just added my expected output

Comment: Why is  row 1 and row 2 yes? why is A 2020-10-13 a yes? and B 2020-10-13 a no??

Comment: My intention is to know if the samples have been seen in the last 7 days, including the date of 'sampling'. 2020-10-13 is a 'yes' for A as it was seen in the 7 days prior (1 sample on 2020-10-10 and 2 samples on 2020-10-11), B was not however (last seen on 2020-10-06 counting backwards from 2020-10-13) and therefore a 'no'.

Comment: Do you only have 2 types, or are there more?

Comment: There are more types in my real dataset (828 types in fact), running many months, so I expect the resulting data frame to very large!

Comment: What do you mean by B was not seen? There was a B in 2020-10-12 hence the B in 2020-10-13 should be a yes

Comment: Sorry, I think you may be looking at the 'expected output'? In the original data frame at the beginning of the question there is no sample type B? There are no sample type 'B' seen after 2020-10-06.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution that uses `zoo` (and `dplyr`, which I'm inferring you're already using):

```r
library(dplyr)
eg <- expand.grid(Sample.Type = unique(dat$Sample.Type),
                  date = seq(min(dat$date), max(dat$date), by = "day"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dat %>%
  mutate(a=TRUE) %>%
  full_join(eg, by = c("Sample.Type", "date")) %>%
  mutate(a=!is.na(a)) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  group_by(Sample.Type) %>%
  mutate(last7 = zoo::rollapplyr(a, 7, any, partial = TRUE)) %>%
  select(-a) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  print(n=99) 
# # A tibble: 29 x 3
#    Sample.Type date       last7
#    <chr>       <date>     <lgl>
#  1 A           2020-10-05 TRUE 
#  2 B           2020-10-05 TRUE 
#  3 A           2020-10-06 TRUE 
#  4 B           2020-10-06 TRUE 
#  5 B           2020-10-06 TRUE 
#  6 B           2020-10-06 TRUE 
#  7 A           2020-10-07 TRUE 
#  8 B           2020-10-07 TRUE 
#  9 A           2020-10-08 TRUE 
# 10 B           2020-10-08 TRUE 
# 11 A           2020-10-09 TRUE 
# 12 B           2020-10-09 TRUE 
# 13 A           2020-10-10 TRUE 
# 14 B           2020-10-10 TRUE 
# 15 A           2020-10-11 TRUE 
# 16 A           2020-10-11 TRUE 
# 17 B           2020-10-11 TRUE 
# 18 A           2020-10-12 TRUE 
# 19 B           2020-10-12 TRUE 
# 20 A           2020-10-13 TRUE 
# 21 B           2020-10-13 FALSE
# 22 A           2020-10-14 TRUE 
# 23 B           2020-10-14 FALSE
# 24 A           2020-10-15 TRUE 
# 25 B           2020-10-15 FALSE
# 26 A           2020-10-16 TRUE 
# 27 B           2020-10-16 FALSE
# 28 A           2020-10-17 TRUE 
# 29 B           2020-10-17 FALSE
```

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(Sample.Type = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), date = structure(c(18540, 18540, 18541, 18541, 18541, 18541, 18545, 18546, 18546, 18550, 18551, 18552), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Sorry, I ran your code and this error came up: "Error in is.data.frame(y) : object 'eg' not found". Would you also know why your dates are in numeric format? Does that matter?

Comment: (1) `eg` not found, did you miss it in the answer? (2) `numeric` ... no, they are `Date` class, which is internally numeric. If your `"date"` column is a string instead, then you really need to state that, and ... they should not be strings.

Comment: Thank you - my mistake, I did miss it. This worked a treat!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `lag()` while grouping by `Sample.Type`.

1. Toy dataset. I just added a third Sample.Type

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

typeday <- tibble(
    Sample.Type = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A","B", "C", "C"),
    date = as.Date(c("2020-10-05", "2020-10-05", "2020-10-06",
                     "2020-10-06", "2020-10-11", "2020-10-17",
                     "2020-10-17", "2020-10-17", "2020-10-18"))
    )

typeday
#> # A tibble: 9 x 2
#>   Sample.Type date      
#>   <chr>       <date>    
#> 1 A           2020-10-05
#> 2 B           2020-10-05
#> 3 A           2020-10-06
#> 4 B           2020-10-06
#> 5 A           2020-10-11
#> 6 A           2020-10-17
#> 7 B           2020-10-17
#> 8 C           2020-10-17
#> 9 C           2020-10-18
```

2. Then, make sure you have the right order for the types and dates. Once you group by Sample.Type, evaluate if the last date (`lag(date)`) is greater or equal than seven days behind your actual date. From there it is just cleaning the `sampled` column. You can also arrange by only date after ungrouping.

```r
typeday %>% 
    arrange(Sample.Type, date) %>% 
    group_by(Sample.Type) %>% 
    mutate(
        sampled = lag(date) >= date - days(7),
        sampled = case_when(
            sampled ~ "yes",
            !sampled | is.na(sampled) ~ "no"
        )
    ) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    arrange(date)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>   Sample.Type date       sampled
#>   <chr>       <date>     <chr>  
#> 1 A           2020-10-05 no     
#> 2 B           2020-10-05 no     
#> 3 A           2020-10-06 yes    
#> 4 B           2020-10-06 yes    
#> 5 A           2020-10-11 yes    
#> 6 A           2020-10-17 yes    
#> 7 B           2020-10-17 no     
#> 8 C           2020-10-17 no     
#> 9 C           2020-10-18 yes
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>